# Tag not working only in live landing page subdomain

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have these 2 tags that works properly except for the landing pages hosted by our LP builder provider RDStation. One sends the conversion to Google Analytics and the other to Facebook. Both are triggered by one element visibility. What I'm tracking is a Form engagement with 3 steps. I'm expecting an event on GA and FB after the completion of the first step.

These tags work on the preview mode and both Pixel and Tag Manager are present in the live pages. The Form in other pages outside this host is the same code.  I've tried to move code around, edit the form, edit and recreate tags and triggers. With no success. For some reason, very occasionally the tags work. I wasn't able to isolate the cause tho.

Stuck in this for 2 days, any ideas?

LP: https://materiais.bodyscience.pt/endermologia-02-2021-cons-online

Answer (score 0):

If you have published the GTM with updated tags in my opinion the problem may be due to the way your page is made. If you look at the source of page you can see that the Tag Manager snippet is there 2 times, you have 2 times the `head` tag and 2 times the `body` tag ... Probably some conflict may be due to this, so first fix the page correctly and then try again.